# Why should I use (String[])null over null in java?

Tags: java

In some snippets, I noticed that the array is initialized by casting the `null` value to `String` array like:

```
String[] array = (String[])null;
```

Generally, `null` is used to initialize variables e.g. an array of strings like:

```
String[] array = null;
```

When or why should I cast null values to string array or any other data type like this?

Comment: There's never any reason to choose the first one.

Comment: first one is type casting .

Comment: You should never set any *collection type* to `null` in te first place! Doing so will force you to do *null checks* later which are not needed otherwise.

Comment: is that `null` casted to **String[]**? sorry for the question.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle That's not a collection type, that's an array type. Your statement is false in other ways too.

Comment: @LKTN.25 yes, check Eran's answer, it can be used for to select overloaded method when passing null argument.

Comment: @Kayaman what is the purpose of an array? hold a bunch of object references. This is exactly the same purpose of any implementation of the `Collection` interface. But if it makes you feel better keep nitpicking.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Or why don't we all just say wrong things here, because you don't need to be precise in programming. Let's call arrays collections and say stupid claims that you should never set collection types to null. Or we could try to make sure that the information given here is correct, what do you think?

Comment: *"Or why don't we all just say wrong things here,"* are you familiar with the concept of *generalisation*? The main point of my comment was was about the `null` assignmet and **not** to tell that arrays are collections. I beleve the OP will understand that, since novices tent to (mis-) use arrays as collections. That you started an argument about the "arrays are not collections" thing makes it look more important  that it is from the OPs perspective.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle If you don't want to be corrected, don't make wrong statements. The [array type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1) is distinct from a collection, even if you can store elements in both. On the other hand, saying that you should never assign a null to (either) one is just plain wrong.

Comment: A crucial difference is that collections support resizing, while arrays do not. So if you don't yet know how many elements you need, an empty Collection will do just fine; a `new String[0]` will not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need to use

```
String[] array = (String[]) null;
```

You might have to use `(String[]) null` if you pass a `null` value to an overloaded method (i.e. one of multiple methods having the same name) and you want the method that accepts a `String[]` argument to be chosen by the compiler.

For example, if you have the following methods :

```
public void doSomething (Integer i) {}
public void doSomething (String s) {}
public void doSomething (String[] arr) {}
```

Calling `doSomething (null)` will not pass compilation, since the compiler won't know which method to choose.

Calling `doSomething ((String[]) null)` will execute the 3rd method.

Of course, you can assign the `null` to a `String[]` variable, and avoid the casting :

```
String[] arr = null;
doSomething (arr);
```

Comment: And, casting to `String` or `Integer` will invoke an appropriate cast.

Comment: same also happens if you have a single method with varargs `public void doSomethingElse(String... values)` - if passing `null` is not possible to distinct between values being null, or its first element being null